# scala test - how to stub curry method

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have this method

```
  def addFriend(friendId:String)(userId:String)
```

I am trying to stub it like this :

```
 (repositoryMock.addFriend(_:String)(_:String)) when ("bar","foo") returns true
```

but of course it will not work .
and couldn't do something like (doesn't compile)

```
 (repositoryMock.addFriend(_:String)(_:String)) when ("bar")("foo") returns true
```

any ideas ?

Comment: What mocking framework are you using?

Comment: @ben scalamock, using mockfactory

Comment: Can you post the error you got with `when ("bar","foo")`? I'm able to successfully use this pattern with the following: `trait Foo { def bar(x: Int)(y: Int): Int }; val foo = stub[Foo]; (foo.bar(_: Int)(_: Int)) when(5, 6) returns 10`

Comment: Hi, it is embarrassing , but you are right , my bad ! I missed the params order . thank you so much. you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is what you first tried - put all the curried arguments in a single list:

```
(repositoryMock.addFriend(_:String)(_:String)) when ("bar", "foo") returns true
```